# $watch in controller not firing on pushing items into array in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-watch

I have a two-way binded variable `publish.selected_tags` between a directive and a controller.

I have kept a `$watch` on that variable in my controller:

```
$scope.$watch('publish.selected_tags', function(new_val, old_val) {
    console.log(new_val); //print new value
})
```

The problem I am facing is that **when I push** an item into the `selected_tags` list, the `$watch` is not fired:

```
return {
    scope: {
        selected_tags: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.selected_tags.push('item') //watch in the controller not getting fired
    }
}
```

However, **when I assign** `selected_tags` to an array the `$watch` in the controller gets fired:

```
return {
    scope: {
        selected_tags: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.selected_tags = ['item'] //watch in the controller getting fired!
    }
}
```

Why is this happening? How can I get my `$watch` to fire in the case where I want to push an element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $scope.$watchCollection(...)

Ref. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Answer (score 1):

`$watch` is for watching on properties on scope. if you want to watch a collection you need to use `$watchCollection`(For shallow watching) or `$watch('publish.selected_tags', function(newVal, oldVal){}, true)` (For deep watching).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `$watchCollection()` to watch for changes in an array. `$watch()` fires when the value of the expression changes, not on property change inside the object you're watching if I'm not mistaken.

See https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection